# How to get hardware information from VMs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We are migrating our production environment from DigitalOcean to GCP.
However, because it is different, we don't know where to get some information about our VMs.

Is it possible to have a report that tells me the amount of CPUs, Machine Type, amount of RAM, amount of SSD and amount of SSD used by VM?

Comment: Like on the console itself or programmatically using APIs? GCP introduced a new [observability](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances/observability) tab for highlighting that info.

Comment: This should be posted to [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com), not Stack Overflow (it's an infrastructure question, not a programming question)

Answer (score 1):

Compute Engine lets you export detailed [reports of your Compute Engine usage](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/usage-export) (daily & monthly) to a Cloud Storage bucket using the usage export feature. Usage reports provide information about the lifetime of your resources.

[VM instance insights](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/view-and-understand-vm-insights) help you understand the CPU, memory, and network usage of your Compute Engine VMs.

As @Dharmaraj mentioned in the comment, GCP introduced a new [observability](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances/observability) tab designed to give insights into common scenarios and issues associated with CPU, Disk, Memory, Networking, and live processes. With access to all of this data in one location, you can easily correlate between signals over a given time frame.

Finally, the [Stackdriver agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent) can be installed on GCE VMs, allowing additional [metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics#agent) like memory monitoring. You can also use Stackdriver's [notification and alerting](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/) features. However, [premium-tier accounts](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing) are the only ones that can access agent metrics.